# R code produces different output for equation in loop every time

Tags: r, geometric-mean

I'm trying to calculate the geometric mean and find the maximum possible value for it for a certain set of parameters. I am convoluting two distributions (I think, not sure about the terms in english), one of which is the probability density function of my equation, and want to find the set of parameters where the geometric mean is the highest. I'll try to annotate my code, so that it gets clearer what I'm doing. I'm doing this to determine the optimal niche width for a species under certain cirumstances. The fitness depends on the match between the trait of the species and the standard deviation of the Environment `sdH` and a trade-off function.

However, if I change one of the parameters, it changes the complete output, even though I would not expect it to do so. Maybe I am overlooking some mistake or this is acutally to be expected and my expectations are wrong, but I am at my wits end. Maybe someone has any idea how to do this?

```
deltax=0.5    #This is the step size for one of the distributions
alpha=c(1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4)    #These are one set of parameters I want to study. They are each a distinct case.
H=seq(-7, 7, deltax)    #This is the scope of the x-values for one distribution
sdH=seq(1, 7, 0.02)    #This is the scope of the standard deviation I want to study
optimumgvariance= matrix(0,ncol = length(alpha), nrow = length(sdH)) #a matrix to store my final values
```

This is the first set of parameters I'm using in the follwing code:

```
for (l in 1:length(sdH)){  #for each value of sdH I do the following:  
  g=seq(0.1, 9, 0.1)    # set up a vector of values, which determine the width of the other distribution
  gt=0    #initialize a helper variable
  tradeoff=numeric(length(g))     #initilaize a vector for the results of one of my equations
  expfitnessgeo=numeric(length(g))    #initiliaze a vector for the geometric mean
  optimumg=numeric(length(alpha))    #initialize a vector for the optimum value of g (the values from above) for the given set of parameters (depending on which loop we are in)
  for (k in 1:length(alpha)){    #for all values of alpha we do the following
    for (i in 1:length(g)){    #for all values of g
      gt=-(g[i]^2)    #I calculate the helper variabel gt (for clearer code futher below)
      tradeoff[i]=exp(gt/(2*alpha[k]^2))    #I calculate the results of the trade-off function for the combination of g and alpha in the current loop
      survival=numeric(length(H))    #I set up a vector to contain the results of the next equation
      for (j in 1:length(H)){    
        survival[j]=tradeoff[i]*exp(-((H[j])^2/(g[i]^2)))    #the survival
      }    
      expfitnessgeo[i]= exp(sum(log(survival)*dnorm(H, 0, sdH[l])*deltax)) # the maximum long term fitness can be identified by a maximum geometric mean of the probability density function    
    }    
    print(max(expfitnessgeo))    #just to control the output
    if(max(expfitnessgeo)>=0.1){    #the geometric mean needs to be larger than 0.1 
      optimumg[k]=g[which(expfitnessgeo==max(expfitnessgeo))]  #the optimal value of g is the one where the geometric mean of the pdf is maximal.  
    } else optimumg[k]=0    #if the geometric mean of the pdf is smaller than 0.1 I set the optimum g to zero

  }    
  optimumgvariance[l,] =optimumg #store the results in the matrix    
}
```

This produces results as I would expect:

```
> tail(optimumgvariance)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[296,]    0    0  3.3  4.1  4.7
[297,]    0    0  3.3  4.1  4.7
[298,]    0    0  3.3  4.1  4.7
[299,]    0    0  3.3  4.1  4.7
[300,]    0    0  3.3  4.1  4.7
[301,]    0    0  3.3  4.1  4.7
> max(optimumgvariance[,2])
[1] 2.3
> max(optimumgvariance[,1])
[1] 1.5
```

However, when I only change the scope of `sdH=seq(1,10,0.02)` and leave everthing else as it is, the results change. I suddenly have values in the second column, where I previously had the expected zeros:

```
deltax=0.5    
alpha=c(1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4)    
H=seq(-7, 7, deltax)    
sdH=seq(1, 10, 0.02)    
optimumgvariance= matrix(0,ncol = length(alpha), nrow = length(sdH))    

   > tail(optimumgvariance)    
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]    
[446,]    0  2.9  3.4  4.1  4.8    
[447,]    0  2.9  3.4  4.1  4.8    
[448,]    0  2.9  3.4  4.1  4.8    
[449,]    0  2.9  3.4  4.1  4.8    
[450,]    0  2.9  3.4  4.1  4.8    
[451,]    0  2.9  3.4  4.1  4.8    
> max(optimumgvariance[,1])    
[1] 1.5
```

I would expect that the values in column 2 stay as before, but somehow they don't. And this goes even further, when I put `sdH= seq(1,15, 0.02)` I even get values other than zero in the first column:

```
deltax=0.5
alpha=c(1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4)
H=seq(-7, 7, deltax)
sdH=seq(1, 15, 0.02)
optimumgvariance= matrix(0,ncol = length(alpha), nrow = length(sdH))

> tail(optimumgvariance)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[696,]  2.4    3  3.4  4.2  4.8
[697,]  2.4    3  3.4  4.2  4.8
[698,]  2.4    3  3.4  4.2  4.8
[699,]  2.4    3  3.4  4.2  4.8
[700,]  2.4    3  3.4  4.2  4.8
[701,]  2.4    3  3.4  4.2  4.8
```

Does anybody have any idea, what causes this? I actually wanted to go up to `sdH= seq(1,30, 0.02)` but I can't trust my results when I don't know why this happens.

Comment: I think your problem is here: `dnorm(H, 0, sdH[l])` as you are changing the values of sdH from 7 to 10 onto 15, this the final value from the dnorm function is increasing.  Commenting the code would help other debug your code.

Comment: @Dave2e: I'm not so sure what you mean? Does the final value sdH takes in the last loop influence the behavior in the previous ones? I'll try to comment what I'm doing but english is my second language so I'll have to look up some of the terms... Thanks!

Comment: I added more information and comments. I hope that helps.

Comment: The comments help.  When you change the terms in: `sdH=seq(1, 15, 0.02)` the length of the calculation changes.  If you run your last case and compare the `optimumgvariance[296:301,]` and `optimumgvariance[446:451,]` you will obtain the results from the previous cases.  I am sorry but I don't know survival analysis well enough to determine if you have a logic error.

Comment: Thanks! That actually helps. The equations and such I'm sure are correct, so I shouldn't ahve a logic error. My explanation could suffer from me doing math only in my native language and not in english... I still don't know where the non-zero-values in the first columns come from though, in the cases where I have a broader spectrum of sdH. I thought, that once I get zeros, there should be only more zeros. Any idea on that? I think, it might be how I store the values in the matrix. But that's just a gut feeling...Thanks so much!